# Aligning text box to bottom right of Google Slides using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, alignment

After much head-banging, I'm coming to Stack Overflow for help! I'm using a Google App script to automatically add today's date to all my slides. The function I have works, but it adds the date to the center of the slide - I can't find any option that will let me place it in the bottom right of the slide. AlignPosition only seems to have three parameters -- CENTER, HORIZONTAL CENTER, VERTICAL CENTER, so I'm not sure if there's an alternate path that using this?

```
function myFunction() {
 var date = new Date();
 var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
 "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
 var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
 var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, 300, 200, 300, 60);
 var textRange = shape.getText();
 textRange.setText(months[date.getMonth()]+' '+date.getDate()+', '+date.getFullYear())
}
```

This function works, but again it aligns the text in the middle of the slide.

Answer (score 0):

About your question of `I can't find any option that will let me place it in the bottom right of the slide.`, from your showing script, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put a shape with a width of 300 pt and a height of 60 pt into the bottom right of the slide.
- You want to put the text to the bottom right of the slide.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var date = new Date();
  var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var s = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  var pageWidth = s.getPageWidth();
  var pageHeight = s.getPageHeight();
  var shapeWidth = 300; // This is from your script.
  var shapeHeight = 60; // This is from your script.
  var left = pageWidth - shapeWidth;
  var top = pageHeight - shapeHeight;
  var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.TEXT_BOX, left, top, shapeWidth, shapeHeight);
  shape.setContentAlignment(SlidesApp.ContentAlignment.BOTTOM);
  var textRange = shape.getText();
  textRange.setText(months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ', ' + date.getFullYear());
  textRange.getParagraphStyle().setParagraphAlignment(SlidesApp.ParagraphAlignment.END);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained. In order to have a high readability of the result, I added the border color of the slide and the shape. In the actual result, the border is not shown.

[image]

#### References:

- [insertShape(shapeType, left, top, width, height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertShape(ShapeType,Number,Number,Number,Number))
- [setContentAlignment(contentAlignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#setcontentalignmentcontentalignment)
- [setParagraphAlignment(alignment)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/paragraph-style#setParagraphAlignment(ParagraphAlignment))